# Firebase Admin SDK initializeApp returns invalid_token

Tags: firebase, firebase-admin

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("service_account.json")

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://******.firebaseio.com"
});
```

Returns:

> Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the
> "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access
> token with the following error: "Error fetching access token:
> invalid_grant (Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a
> reasonable timeframe)". The most likely cause of this error is using a
> certificate key file which has been revoked. Make sure the key ID for
> your key file is still present at
> https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/project.
> If not, generate a new key file at
> https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/serviceaccounts/adminsdk.

The `service_account` and Key ID are present.

Comment: Server time was not synced. This thread was helpful in resolving, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712965/how-to-connect-to-firebase-by-firebase-admin-against-a-proxy

Comment: I'll make sure to add this case to the error message for an upcoming release so that future developers don't come across this issue. Thank you for reporting it! I'm glad you got it all figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The same incident happened to me. I have a structure that admin is nodejs, client is android and ios. This happened to me when i tried to run in my local host then i moved admin to heroku and it solved.

Comment: Server time was not synced. You probably ran into the issue. This thread was helpful in resolving, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712965/how-to-connect-to-firebase-by-firebase-admin-against-a-proxy

Answer (score 0):

i ran into the same problem when using the node js firebase SDK.

in the error message there are two possible course (1) wrong or expired credentials. (2)re-sync the time on your server

the second error occurs due to wrong date and time on your computer,
you can force Windows 10 time to synch with a time server by doing the following:

Follow the steps mentioned below.

Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> and select Command prompt(Admin).

Type each one of the command below and press enter.

```
net stop w32time

w32tm /unregister

w32tm /register

net start w32time

w32tm /resync
```

Restart the computer to test the issue again.
[image]

try making your request again and it should work.