# Not able to send device push notification due to app/invalid-credential error

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, push-notification

I am trying to send device push notification using firebase in cordova (fcm-node
 plugin for node) using this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node) ,I have got the device registration token but when I try to send the notification to registered device,getting below error:

> { Error: Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND accounts.google.com accounts.google.com:443".
>       at FirebaseAppError.Error (native)
>       at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (C:\Users\212606402\Learning\Alert server\pushalert-server\alert-push-notification-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:25:28)
>       at new FirebaseAppError (C:\Users\212606402\Learning\Alert server\pushalert-server\alert-push-notification-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\utils\error.js:70:23)
>       at C:\Users\212606402\Learning\Alert server\pushalert-server\alert-push-notification-server\node_modules\firebase-admin\lib\firebase-app.js:78:23
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)
>     errorInfo:
>      { code: 'app/invalid-credential',
>        message: 'Credential implementation provided to initializeApp() via the "credential" property failed to fetch a valid Google OAuth2 access token with the following error: "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND accounts.google.com accounts.google.com:443".' } }

Can anyone please help me what is wrong here.

I saw this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41712965/how-to-connect-to-firebase-by-firebase-admin-against-a-proxy) also but it's a different error.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is to update your systems date/time.

For windows system better is to synchronize time with Internet time server.