# Firestore updates SOMETIMES fail with error "Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials."

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using "firebase-admin" (v6.4.0) npm package in nodejs (v6.9.4) to connect with firestore (using a service account .json file).

**Everything works fine** (read/updates work properly) **BUT SOMETIMES** I receive

```
"Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential."
```

Entire ERROR -

```
{ Error: 16 UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
    at Object.exports.createStatusError (/home/ec2-user/socialhelpouts/deployment/social-helpouts/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:87:15)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (/home/ec2-user/socialhelpouts/deployment/social-helpouts/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1214:28)
    at InterceptingListener._callNext (/home/ec2-user/socialhelpouts/deployment/social-helpouts/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:590:42)
    at InterceptingListener.onReceiveStatus (/home/ec2-user/socialhelpouts/deployment/social-helpouts/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:640:8)
    at callback (/home/ec2-user/socialhelpouts/deployment/social-helpouts/node_modules/google-gax/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:867:24)
  code: 16,
  metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: { 'www-authenticate': [Object] } },
  details: 'Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.' }
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109979/firestore-code-16-request-had-invalid-authentication-credentials) and used [chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/) as suggested by my cloud provider AWS [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-time.html) to keep my server time in sync.
Time is in sync now, but I still receive the same error.

Since it works most (~95%) of the time and fails occasionally (with exactly the same code), I don't have a reproducible code.

Comment: Are you using transactions? how many records per operation are you using (Ej. 10.000 reads)

Comment: nope, not using transactions.

Comment: did you get answer, I am getting same issue?